# Cache manifest caches network files

Tags: php, html, caching, browser-cache, cache-manifest

I'm having an issue with my cache manifest file. This is what it looks like (some files have been removed from the list to make it shorter):

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#r8

CACHE:
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
css/bootstrap.min.css
css/receipt.min.css
css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css

NETWORK:
index.php
*
http://*
```

I've had some trouble with index.php caching so I cleared my cache and opened the console in Google Chrome, then I reloaded the page.

```
Application Cache Progress event (12 of 13) http://www.magnusburton.com/stackd/index.php:1
Application Cache Progress event (13 of 13)
Application Cache UpdateReady event
```

From what I can see, it looks like Chrome is still caching index.php even if it's under the *NETWORK* section.

How can I prevent any browser from caching this file?

Comment: Is your manifest file referred from index.php itself ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - The page referencing the appcache manifest will always get cached, even though you specify it to not get cached.

See green section of 6.7.3.3, just below 32. here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#parsing-cache-manifests